# trying to animate on a javascript canvas

Tags: javascript, animation, canvas, vector, setinterval

as the title said i'm trying to animate on a java canvas but i'm not sure how to add on to the vector class of my objects current position
I've been told to use this:

```
Bus.prototype.update = function()
{
    this.getPosition().add(new Vector(10.0));
}
```

but it doesn't recognize the .add function and comes up with an error when i use my setInterval function

I'll include my get/set functions aswell just incase

```
Bus.prototype.getPosition = function()  {       
    return this.mPosition;
};
Bus.prototype.setPosition = function (pPosition)    {
    this.mPosition = pPosition;
};
```

I'm pretty new at coding so i apologize if this is very vague or badly written

Comment: Lesson 1: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/245062/whats-the-difference-between-javascript-and-java

Answer (score 0):

jsFiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/CanvasCode/41z9o10p/1/

javascript

```
var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");

var Bear = function(xSet, ySet)
{
    this.XPos = xSet;
    this.YPos = ySet;
}

Bear.prototype.updatePosition = function(xValue, yValue)
{
    this.XPos += xValue;
    this.YPos += yValue;
}

var bear = new Bear(0,0);

setInterval( function()
            {
    ctx.fillStyle = "#000";
    ctx.fillRect(0,0,c.width,c.height);
    ctx.fillStyle = "#0F0";
    ctx.fillRect(bear.XPos, bear.YPos, 50,50);

    bear.updatePosition(0.2, 0.4);
} ,1);
```

Bear is a custom "class". All bear has is a X position and a Y position, the constructor can take in two values which will set the X and Y value. I then add a new method to `Bear` which is called `updatePosition`. All updatePosition does it take in two values and add them to the original X position and Y position (you can also provide negative numbers to move the opposite way). Now with our Bear we can create one and then use its `updatePosition` function and move it.